# How to manipulate label of form2 in form3

Tags: c#

I am trying to have a button in `Form3` change a label's text in `Form1` and `Form2`. 
I have gotten it to work somewhat but in order to have the label change I have to have the mouse click on it. This is my current code in form 1 and 2:

`label1.Text = Form3.myNameClass.myName;`

and this is code in form 3

```
public class tournamentNameClass
{
    public static string tournamentName;
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myNameClass.myName = textBox3.Text;
}
```

How can I make it so that I dont need to press the label to get it to change?

Comment: One good approach would be create event listeners on both `form1` and `form2` and subscribe `form3` for those. Assuming you're not using already another `MV*` framework, that could work just fine

Comment: Agreed, create a custom event on Form3 that is triggered by the button click. Alternatively, pass form1 and form2 references to form3 and have that button click code push the updates to form1 and 2

Comment: This is my first ever c# program and that sounds very hard? could u explain it more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are at the start of learning, I'm not going to go in events and delegates.

My example demonstrates how you manipulate a control on `Form1` from `Form2` directly. You should be able to figure this out for `Form3` easily by yourself, and is together a good practice of understanding.

*(I want to state that there are many different methods/techniques for passing data or manipulate controls between forms, I guess this is the easiest one for you to understand as a beginner, as this is the most simplistic approach of all)*

## Form1 Designer

First we make `label1` its modifier to **Public** (so we can reach it in another class) in the designer like so:

[image: label1 designer]

## Form1 code behind

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // With the keyword "this" we pass in Form1, the current instance we are in
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

## Form2 code behind

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 _form1;

    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form1.label1.Text = "lets change the text";
    }
}
```

We are passing `Form1` completely in the constructor, this could easily be the `label1` control alone.

## Result

[image: result]

Comment: The button I press to display the name is in form 3 and it displays name in form 1 and 2. You have buttons in all forms from what I can tell?

Comment: button1_click in Form1 just opens Form2

Comment: All the forms are open from app launch already. 

public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Form2 formSecond = new Form2();
            Form3 formThird = new Form3();
            formThird.Show();
            formSecond.Show();
        }

Comment: Myeah, It's the same, I just used a button to open the form in my example.

Comment: So that means I can just ignore everything in Form1 code behind and just add the things to form2 ?

Comment: I understand you have almost no knowledge about this however I encourage you to read/watch and research some basic training about winforms. You will come back a lot smarter in a faster way. Shortly I can show you how it's done, but it's impossible to teach you the basics trough comments. Hope you understand.

Comment: With screenshots, Gifs and explanation this is whole new level of answering question. Keep it up!!

Comment: Ok I got it to work, thank you Jim for this detailed answer and for being so accepting of my lack of knowledge. I am reading c# books and taking lynda courses to learn c#. If you know of any helpful content id be more than happy to read/watch/listen to them. This is by far the most detailed answer I have ever seen with the gifs and all. Have a nice day

Comment: @FelixTorssell your welcome. Youtube, Google and SO will be your best friends.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you only need to trigger a redraw on forms 1 and 2.

after you set the text of the label, try calling `labelControl.Refresh()`

Or you could call refresh on form1 and form2 if that's any easier (that is a bit heavy handed though)

This will instruct the forms to redraw their visual representation based on how the data is set in the form currently.

Update:

You will need to invert your logic somewhat..

Rather than having a reverence to form 3 from form 1 and form 2, you will need to have a reference to form 1 and 2 from form3.. (woah so many form)

So then your button click method would look like this

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1.label1.Text = textBox3.Text;
    form2.label1.Text = textBox3.Text;
    form1.label1.Refresh();
    form2.label1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: You mean simply adding labelControl.Refresh() after label1.Text = Form3.myNameClass.myName;? or what do u mean?

Comment: That was my original idea but the problem is that. labels are inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: @FelixTorssell you need to write mutators for the labels. i.e.

public void setLabelText(string newValue)
{
    this.label1.Text = newValue;
    this.Label1.Refresh();
}